# Allow users to be notified via Slack when they are included in "Ask team members"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

When a question is asked in SO for Teams there's a "Ask team members" textbox that is certainly useful. However, once the question is posted these users are notified exclusively via email, which is not an especially dynamic communication channel.

It would be great if users could choose to be notified via Slack when they are included in the "Ask team members" list for a question. I guess that this could be implemented via a "Notify me via Slack when I'm asked a question" checkbox in the user profile, and that the user should somehow verify his identity in the appropriate Slack workspace (I guess the Slack API provides means to do so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already a feature in Teams. When setting up a Slack notification you can select "@mentions (when someone @mentions me)". This is a per user setting though. Each user in the Team must authenticate with Slack and setup the notification.

Comment: I knew about the per-user Slack notifications setting, but I didn't know that it also applied to "Ask team members" cases (thinking about it, it makes total sense). Thanks!